# Longest Subsequence of a given String in Java

Tags: java

I am being asked a question which says 'Given an input string. Find the longest subsequence's length and the starting index of it'.

I am confused here. Isn't the longest subsequence of an input string equivalent to the string itself? What do they want from me?

Comment: Are you asking what is a subsequence String or how to get the String?

Comment: There might be a word you are missing? Usually people ask for things like longest increasing/decreasing subsequence of a sequence of like longest common subsequence of two sequences.

Comment: I'm confused too. According to the Wikipedia article tomerpacific referred to, the sequence "apple" is a subsequence of the word "apple".

Comment: You're right: the question is imprecise; you should ask for clarification to the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

To quote Wikipedia, a subsequence is:

> A sequence that can be derived from another sequence by deleting some or no elements without changing the order of the remaining elements.

So for example, if you have the string "abcd", the subsequences of it will be:

```
abc, abd, acd, bcd, abcd
```